# How to suppress drilldown on subreports in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a main report, that contains a sub report at the group footer. While double clicking the subreport at run time the sub report is drill down and opens in new tab. I want to disable the drill down feature. I cannot able to put the sub report inside a textbox to achieve this. AS the sub report grows dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drill-down feature can NOT be disabled.  Moreover, you will not be able to embed a sub-report in a text objects.  You can, however, disable the sub-report's ability to expand vertically--clear the 'can grow' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `EnableDrillDown` property that you can set to `false`, but this applies it to the ***whole*** report (not just the subreport). I'm working in ASP.NET WebForms so for me it was just:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.EnableDrillDown = false;
```

It should be the same if you are doing it in WinForms, but I'm not 100% sure.